# Convert query using REGEX and CONCAT() to Doctrine queryBuilder using expr()

Tags: php, mysql, regex, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm writing a `REGEXP` query using the [beberlei doctrine extension](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) `DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Regexp`

My working SQL query is:

```
WHERE (
    'http://www.example.com/product/1' REGEXP concat('^.*', `url`, '.*$') 
    AND
    `url_type` = 'contains'
)
```

`url` and `url_type` are fields in my MySQL table.

I have this working in queryBuilder as follows:

```
$qb->expr()->andX(
    $qb->expr()->eq('e.urlType', $qb->expr()->literal('contains')),
    'REGEXP(:url, CONCAT(:anythingBefore, e.url, :anythingAfter)) = 1'
)
->setParameter('anythingBefore', '^.*')
->setParameter('anythingAfter', '.*$')
->setParameter('url', $url);
```

Is it possible to re-write this using the following `$expr()` so I don't have to pass regular expression parts as parameters and also so I can create more complex regular expressions?

```
$qb->expr()->concat($qb->expr()->literal('^.*'), 'e.url', $qb->expr()->literal('.*$'))
```